# How to convert Map keys into a Set efficiently without copying and rebuilding the set in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

While I can do

```
const set = new Set(map.keys())
```

it requires rebuilding the set. I would also like to avoid pre-building a duplicate set for the return. The function for returning this set can also build the set from arrays. Therefore, the return needs to share a common interface with set.
I need the set for checking if another input value is in the set, and I need to unroll the returned set into array later as

```
if (set.has(val)) doSomething();
// assign list somewhere
const list = [...set]
```

Therefore, I would like an efficient way to achieve the conversion of map keys to set.

Comment: How do you expect this to work? Can you write some pseudo-code of how you expect this to behave memory-wise? FYI: for all intents and purposes, a Map is a Set that just happens to be in pairs.

Comment: I don't think there is any more "efficient" way of doing it. In all cases you'd have to loop over the keys and do stuff which is similar

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev i think its the other way around a set is a map with k,v same

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev already written the code 
const set = new Set(map.keys())
const list = [...set]

Comment: @PuiHoLam I guess you are overthinking it, and `new Set(map.keys())`(as it uses buildin functions that are faster then JS itself) IS as efficient as you can get, anything else is less efficient

Comment: @Dimava Then someone can just put that down as an answer that typescript as of version xxx doesn't have the feature for them to share the same interface or doesn't have an efficient copy constructor  for this rather than downvoting the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Map` has the same `.has` method as the `set`

```
let m = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])

console.log(m.has('a')) // true
console.log(m.has('c')) // false
```

Comment: Yes, I also said that in the question that it has the has function. But I need to return only the set of keys the the values because the function can also do something else in another condition and build another set of values as I explained in the question. It will be assigned to an option drop down and other functions share the same drop down so I would like them to not have the value return.

Comment: I meant set and map don't share the same interface in typescript.